# SFINAE: static_assert vs std::enable_if

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++14

Are there any disadvantages in the following (**suggested!**) syntax?

```
template< typename T >
void f() static_assert(std::is_same< T, int >::value)
{ ; }
```

instead of SFINAE (that looks like a crutch):

```
template< typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< T, int >::value >::type >
void f() { ; }
```

or even worse:

```
template< typename T >
typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< T, int >::value >::type 
f() 
{ ; }
```

which prohibits using of `auto` deduction of result type.

Comment: `static_assert` is *not* SFINAE, it's an assertion of things that *must be true*.

Comment: that is not a valid c++11 code

Comment: @BЈовић I know. It is just a proposal of possible syntax.

Comment: In the meantime, it's possible to be [more concise](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703021445/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html).

Comment: `static_assert` is _not_ a proposal, it is an accepted part of the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Piotr99 "To use `static_assert` in such syntax" is definitely "proposal". My own proposal.

Comment: @Dukales Well, it's quite useless to propose a new syntax with a keyword that's already defined differently in the standard.

Comment: @Piotr99, nonsense, it's not a problem if the new proposal uses the keyword in a context where it couldn't previously be used, because that doesn't conflict with or alter the meaning of existing code.  For example using the C keyword `static` on class member in C++, or using `extern` for explicit instantiation declarations in C++11, or using `using` for type aliases in C++11, or using `auto` for type deduction in C++11, or using `inline` for namespaces in C++11, or using `mutable` in lambda expressions in C++11, or using `auto` for generic lambdas in C++14, etc. etc.

Comment: That first example of yours doesn't compile for me -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=04d0b7c77ef70dbae87b9f16b63db802-3ac4366c03bbdf3b770d4e4edaa157c5

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's sad but it's true. Please reread the original __Q__.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would using `static_assert` be better than the [Concepts Lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) syntax?

```
template< typename T >
  void f() requires Int<T>()
  { }
```

or:

```
template< Int T >
  void f()
  { }
```

Comment: `static_assert` is only a proposal. I did not know about the existance of the ([proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf)) `requires` keyword before. It looks like the solution.

Comment: @0x499602D2, yes, there's a fork of GCC that implements it, see http://concepts.axiomatics.org/~ans/. You'd need to define the `Int` constraint, e.g. `template<typename T> constexpr bool Int() { return std::is_same< T, int >::value; }`

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but haven't concepts been shelved until C++20 now?

Comment: @Pharap yes, but that doesn't change anything in the answer above, except that you don't need to use a fork of GCC any more. GCC 7 supports concepts, enabled by the `-fconcepts` command-line option.

Comment: @JonathanWakely It might change things if someone was just planning to use concepts lite until 'C++17 concepts' were introduced. That's a whole extra 3 years of being dependant on a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: It's not just a compiler specific extension, it's based on the ISO TS.

Answer (score 26):

First of all, those are different, specifically they are not checked at the same time.

The critical difference is due to their application with regard to overload resolution. SFINAE will cull functions from the overload set, so that another function gets chosen (if any) whereas `static_assert` is applied *after* overload resolution and thus will give an **error** that will stop compilation.

Now, regarding your complaint, you can perfectly use `auto` and SFINAE:

```
// Ensure that T is int
template <typename T>
auto f() -> typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< T, int >::value >::type
{ ... }

// Only pick this overload if begin(c) and end(c) are available
template <typename T>
auto f(T const& c) -> decltype(begin(c), end(c), bool{}) { ... }
```

... and you can perfectly use SFINAE and automatic type deduction

```
template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type>
auto f() { ... }

template <typename T>
auto f(void* =
       typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type*(0))
{ ... }
```

Comment: But my question is about only the verbosity (and what to do with it) of a SFINAE statements in the form in which they are at the moment.

Comment: @Dukales: Ah, yes indeed it is verbose. You could potentially use template aliases for often used tests: `template <typename L, typename R> using enable_if_same = std::enable_if<std::is_same<L, R>::value>::type;` and then `template <typename T, typename = enable_if_same<T, int>> auto f() { ... }` ... also note that real deduction of return types (like for lambdas) is on the plate for C++1y.

Comment: I'm especially interested in new C++ standard's features. Anyways, each SFINAE condition I mostly use once. Therefore aliases is not universal the solution.

Comment: @MatthieuM.   are you sure about the static_assert not involving overload resolution? In a few cases adding static_assert made the code call a different overloaded version of a function. Perhaps it worked there because the overload was a non-template function?

Comment: @peterkarasev: I am sure, overload resolution is only based on the signature whilst `static_assert` appears in the implementation. Likewise, SFINAE is only based on immediate contexts (thus signatures/declarations).